# SSL with Core 2.0 not working

Tags: ssl, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-2.0

`Visual Studio 2017 15.4`, `IIS Express`, `CORE 2.0 MVC`, `Win 7 Ultimate`

I've created a new MVC project with Core 2.0. Without SSL it runs fine:

> LaunchSettings.json

```
       {
      "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": false,
        "anonymousAuthentication": true,
        "iisExpress": {
          "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58087/",
          "sslPort": 0
        }
      },
      "profiles": {
        "IIS Express": {
          "commandName": "IISExpress",
          "launchBrowser": true,
          "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
          }
        },
        "MVCIdenWebApp": {
          "commandName": "Project",
          "launchBrowser": true,
          "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
          },
          "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58088/"
        }
      }
    }
```

When I set it up to use SSL I get a Vis Stud error:
`Unable to connect to web server IISExpress`

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:58087/",
      "sslPort": 44335
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MVCIdenWebApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58088/"
    }
  }
}
```

> Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

I have no problem using SSL with CORE 1.1 projects but get the same error with any CORE 2.0 project.

I've already tried deleting the solution's `.vs folder` and the contents of the `MyDocmuents\IIExpress` folder.

> Partial Solution:

When I added a "launchUrl": to the IIS Express profile using the sslPort the application opens at that address (not the applicationURL): "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44335",

This is different then CORE 1.1 and I do not know if this is the `official` way to do it since I have not been able to find any documentation on how to enable SSL in a Core 2.0 application.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:58087/",
      "sslPort": 44335
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44335/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MVCIdenWebApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58088/"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the "Unable to connect to web server IISExpress" with similar setup config.

Fix for me was to remove a urlacl via elevated cmd prompt.

```
netsh http show urlacl
netsh http delete urlacl https://machine:iisexpressport/
```